# Water and Resonance

Tags: water

I want to confirm this, I’m not 100% sure on the subject and I’ve done a lot of research into this. Does water not only take the shape of the vessel it’s in but also the frequency and or resonance.

If you were to put water into a copper vessel then would that water now or after a set amount of time now carry or adapt to the  for frequency and/or residency of that copper vessel, and or for any other vessel made from any other metal or substances.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, for all interpretations of your vague question I can think of, is 
"no".

First off, the terms "frequency" and "resonance" have a number of applications in physics, but also in pseudoscience and esoteric woo.

If you're talking about the most basic meaning - mechanical resonance: you strike an object, it resonates (more in the case of metal or glass, less in the case of wood or chewing gum) with a mixture of frequencies that depend on the mechanical properties of the object (density, elasticity, damping etc.), on the shape and dimensions of the object, the way it is connected to other objects around it, and the way you hit it. If you fill a copper vessel (or a drinking glass) with water, you change its resonance. Remove the water, the frequency revert to the original state. The mechanical properties of the water stay unchanged.

Also, the liquid itself has a kind of "resonance", i.e., waves of certain frequencies can form in the vessel, while others are suppressed, but those depend on the properties of the water (density, viscosity etc) and the dimensions and shape of the vessel. The properties of the water don't change by being in the vessel, and the shape of the vessel isn't imprinted on the water in any way.

Then you have more advanced meanings, like resonance in response to electromagnetic radiation and the like - for example, water molecules have a resonance frequency that is targeted in microwave ovens to selectively and efficienty heat water. Again, those properties don't change by some liquid being or not being in a container.

What might happen is that the water solves some of the material of the vessel, i.e., your water contains some copper ions after a while. These may have minuscule impact on some physical properties of the water, but most likely not enough to have an impact on some fundamental "resonance".

Then there are the esoteric interpretations of "frequency". As far as I can tell, these are all bullshit and mean whatever the speaker needs them to mean in order to make some preposterous claim. You won't get any conclusive information on those in a physics forum, other than the one I just gave.

Comment: I actually need a good nap before I try and tackle the book you wrote me, with no legitimate sources. Im the type of guy that looks at every aspect. Or every side to a story.

Comment: I wasn’t done, I don’t know who you are or what your back ground is for all I know is your some single sided phiscal minded person that doesn’t believe anything that might be cracked up to be  unsacred science. I came here to learn like probably Many others have. I might not know the exact term for what I was actaully asking. But that wasn’t vague. Everything has a frequency. Or a structural frequency. I wanted to know if water could not only take shape of it’s vessel but it’s natural tunes. frequency. maybe the word frequency is the vague part you talk about. Ima love to hear something else.

Comment: Look, you came to a physics forum. I have studied physics, I answered your question from the point of view of physics, and as far as I can tell, "everything has a frequency" is extremely vague and, depending on the interpretation, either meaningless or wrong. If the answer is not satisfactory, you should be clearer in your question. In particular, how do you measure or detect this "frequency" you're interested in?

Comment: don’t worry when I’m not tried and havent been awake for 26 hours I’ll rewrite a big long properly termed question, with linked resources, and then hopefully that won’t be vague. If I can tag yah I will otherwise I’ll come on here and tell yah what to look for